# React.js error: The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have an issue with my React application (with Redux Saga), I'm getting the console error:

```
The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle.
```

I see this error on the console only on Chrome, not in Firefox or Edge.
This error does not affect my application.

The following steps reproduce the error:
**1. Main page upload.**
[image]
**2. Go to movie details page.**
[image]
**3. Go back to main page.**
[image]

**Main.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { mainActions } from '../../store/actions/actions';
import './Main.scss';
import { MoviesList, SearchPanel } from '../../components';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSearchTextChange = this.handleSearchTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLoadMoreButtonClick = this.handleLoadMoreButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMovieClick = this.handleMovieClick.bind(this);
    this.handleFavoriteMovieClick = this.handleFavoriteMovieClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleComponentDidMount();
  }

  handleComponentDidMount() {
    const { moviesList } = this.props;
    if (!moviesList || moviesList.length <= 0) {
      this.getMovies(null, false);
    }
  }

  handleLoadMoreButtonClick() {
    this.getMovies(null, false);
  }

  handleMovieClick(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'movie') {
      this.props.history.push(`/details/${e.currentTarget.dataset.id}`);
    }
  }

  handleSearchTextChange(e) {
    const { pageNumber, favoriteMoviesList } = this.props;
    this.props.onSearchTextChange({
      searchText: e.target.value,
      pageNumber: pageNumber,
      favoriteMoviesList: favoriteMoviesList
    });
  }

  handleFavoriteMovieClick(e) {
    const { id, name, posterId } = e.currentTarget.dataset;
    const { moviesList, favoriteMoviesList } = this.props;
    this.props.onUpdateFavoriteMovies({
      updatedMovie: { id: id, name: name, posterId: posterId },
      favoriteMoviesList: favoriteMoviesList,
      moviesList: moviesList
    });
  }

  getMovies(updatedSearchText, isSearchChange) {
    const { searchText, pageNumber, favoriteMoviesList } = this.props;
    this.props.onLoadMovies({
      pageNumber: pageNumber,
      favoriteMoviesList: favoriteMoviesList,
      updatedSearchText: isSearchChange ? updatedSearchText : searchText,
      isSearchChange: isSearchChange
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { searchText, isLoadingMoreMovies, isPager, moviesList } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="main-area">
        <SearchPanel
          searchText={searchText}
          onSearchTextChange={this.handleSearchTextChange}
        />
        <MoviesList
          pageName='movies'
          moviesList={moviesList}
          isLoadingMoreMovies={isLoadingMoreMovies}
          isPager={isPager}
          onLoadMoreClick={this.handleLoadMoreButtonClick}
          onMovieClick={this.handleMovieClick}
          onFavoriteMovieClick={this.handleFavoriteMovieClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Main.propTypes = propTypes;
Main.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    searchText: state.main.searchText,
    pageNumber: state.main.pageNumber,
    isLoadingMoreMovies: state.main.isLoadingMoreMovies,
    isPager: state.main.isPager,
    moviesList: state.main.moviesList,
    favoriteMoviesList: state.main.favoriteMoviesList
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onLoadMovies: (request) => dispatch(mainActions.loadMovies(request)),
    onSearchTextChange: (request) => dispatch(mainActions.searchTextChange(request)),
    onUpdateFavoriteMovies: (request) => dispatch(mainActions.updateFavoriteMovies(request))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

**Details.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { detailsActions, mainActions } from '../../store/actions/actions';
import './Details.scss';
import { ActorsList, ButtonClick, CrewsList, FeaturesList, PageTitle, ProductionsList, Rating, Trailer } from '../../components';
import movieUtils from '../../utils/movie.utils';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleBackClick = this.handleBackClick.bind(this);
        this.handleFavoriteMovieClick = this.handleFavoriteMovieClick.bind(this);
        this.isFavorite = false;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleComponentDidMount();
    }

    handleComponentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.moviesList.length <= 0) {
            this.handleBackClick();
            return;
        }
        const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
        if (!movieId) {
            this.handleBackClick();
            return;
        }
        this.props.onLoadMovieDetails(movieId);
        this.updateIsFavorite(movieId);
    }

    numberWithCommas(number) {
        return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    }

    updateIsFavorite(movieId) {
        this.isFavorite = this.props.favoriteMoviesList.findIndex(movie => parseInt(movie.id) === parseInt(movieId)) > -1;
    }

    handleBackClick() {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
    }

    handleFavoriteMovieClick() {
        const { movie, moviesList, favoriteMoviesList } = this.props;
        this.props.onUpdateFavoriteMovies({
            updatedMovie: { id: movie.id, name: movie.title, posterId: movie.poster_path },
            favoriteMoviesList: favoriteMoviesList,
            moviesList: moviesList
        });
        this.updateIsFavorite(movie.id);
    }

    render() {
        const { movie, youtubeKey, credits } = this.props;
        if (!movie) {
            return null;
        }
        const { adult, poster_path, budget, genres, homepage, imdb_id, original_language, original_title,
            overview, popularity, production_companies, production_countries, release_date, revenue, runtime, spoken_languages,
            status, tagline, title, video, vote_average, vote_count } = movie;
        const genresText = genres.map(genre => genre.name).join(', ');
        const countriesText = production_countries.map(country => country.name).join(', ');
        const languagesText = spoken_languages.map(language => language.name).join(', ');
        const featuresList = [
            { item: 'Release Date', value: release_date },
            { item: 'Budget', value: `$${this.numberWithCommas(budget)}` },
            { item: 'Revenue', value: `$${this.numberWithCommas(revenue)}` },
            { item: 'Length', value: `${runtime} minutes` },
            { item: 'Popularity', value: popularity },
            { item: 'Original Title', value: original_title },
            { item: 'For Adults', value: adult ? 'Yes' : 'No' },
            { item: 'Original Language', value: original_language },
            { item: 'Spoken Languages', value: languagesText },
            { item: 'Countries', value: countriesText },
            { item: 'Status', value: status },
            { item: 'Is Video', value: video ? 'Yes' : 'No' }
        ];
        const linksList = [];
        if (homepage) {
            linksList.push({ id: 1, name: 'Homepage', url: homepage });
        }
        if (imdb_id) {
            linksList.push({ id: 2, name: 'IMDB', url: `https://www.imdb.com/title/${imdb_id}` });
        }
        const actorsList = movieUtils.removeDuplicates(credits ? credits.cast ? credits.cast : null : null, 'name');
        const crewsList = movieUtils.removeDuplicates(credits ? credits.crew ? credits.crew : null : null, 'name');
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="details-area">
                    <PageTitle
                        pageName='details'
                        pageTitle='Details'
                    />
                    <ul className="details-content">
                        <li className="details-left" style={{ backgroundImage: `url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${poster_path}')` }}></li>
                        <li className="details-right">
                            <h2>{title} ({release_date.substr(0, 4)})</h2>
                            <p className="genres">{genresText}</p>
                            <p className="description short">{tagline}</p>
                            <Rating
                                rating={vote_average}
                                votesCount={this.numberWithCommas(vote_count)}
                            />
                            <p className="description full">{overview}</p>
                            <div className="extra">
                                <FeaturesList
                                    featuresList={featuresList.slice(0, 5)}
                                    linksList={null}
                                    isFavorite={this.isFavorite}
                                    onFavoriteMovieClick={this.handleFavoriteMovieClick}
                                />
                                {youtubeKey && <Trailer
                                    youtubeKey={youtubeKey}
                                />}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <div className="extra-features">
                            <FeaturesList
                                featuresList={featuresList.slice(5, featuresList.length)}
                                linksList={linksList}
                                isFavorite={null}
                                onFavoriteMovieClick={null}
                            />
                            <ProductionsList
                                productionsList={production_companies}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section className="actors-area">
                    <PageTitle
                        pageName='actors'
                        pageTitle='Cast'
                    />
                    <ActorsList
                        actorsList={actorsList}
                    />
                </section>
                <section className="crew-area">
                    <PageTitle
                        pageName='crew'
                        pageTitle='Crew'
                    />
                    <CrewsList
                        crewsList={crewsList}
                    />
                </section>
                <ButtonClick
                    buttonText={'Back'}
                    buttonTitle={'Back'}
                    isLoading={false}
                    onClick={this.handleBackClick}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Details.propTypes = propTypes;
Details.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        movie: state.details.movie,
        youtubeKey: state.details.youtubeKey,
        credits: state.details.credits,
        moviesList: state.main.moviesList,
        favoriteMoviesList: state.main.favoriteMoviesList
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onLoadMovieDetails: (movieId) => dispatch(detailsActions.loadDetails(movieId)),
        onUpdateFavoriteMovies: (request) => dispatch(mainActions.updateFavoriteMovies(request))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Details);
```

What I already looked in:
[Getting The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064215/getting-the-service-worker-navigation-preload-request-was-cancelled-before-prel)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/108004/getting-the-service-worker-navigation-preload-requ.html
https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4055804?hl=en
https://love2dev.com/pwa/service-worker-preload/

I tried to put this on Details.jsx page, but it didn't work:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(async function () {
        // Respond from the cache if we can
        const cachedResponse = await caches.match(event.request);
        if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse; // Else, use the preloaded response, if it's there
        const response = await event.preloadResponse;
        if (response) return response; // Else try the network.
        return fetch(event.request);
    }());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(async function () {
        // Feature-detect
        if (self.registration.navigationPreload) { // Enable navigation preloads!
            console.log('Enable navigation preloads!');
            await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
        } return;
    })();
});
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this. I'm getting the same error...

Comment: sadly no :( Still have it.

Comment: Have you cleared all your cookies and browser history and stuff. I did and cleared the errors.

Comment: Also, I checked a few conditions in my render method and I had a mistake. I changed a few and it isn't throwing the error any longer. Not sure if this even helps :(

Comment: Nothing helped for me :(

Comment: damn dude... sorry to hear that. Someone told me that it could be useEffect (my project is with hooks). Have you tried there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Had same error, even my iframe wasn't loading..whatever video you are using from youtube use **nocookie/embed** in url. It's working for me.

Try changing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8eBBG46H8A to

https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/i8eBBG46H8A

Hope nocookie & embed helps..!!

Comment: this actually did the trick. Thanks man !

Comment: Docs on using youtube-nocookie.com from youtube.com at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780

Comment: i've tried this solution, but the error message still same.. any other suggest sir? i using nextjs

Comment: The answer works. But what does the error mean or hurt?